# Why It is possible to make outlet of table view in parent Class

Tags: ios, xcode, oop, inheritance, iboutlet

Let say, I have three classes: classA, classB, and BaseClass. I extended Class A and B with the base class like:

```
class A: BaseClass{
}
class B: BaseClass{
}
```

There are two controllers in Storyboard that I bind with class A and class B respectively.

Now My question is when I am trying to drag an outlet of tableview in BaseClass which is present in two controllers which is bindup with class A and B Xcode allow me while BaseClass is parent class. So please tell me why is it possible. And what OOP(Object Oriented Programming) concept is used here?

Answer (score 0):

Yes You can make outlet in Base class and can use into child class. but you have to make connection on both class separately.

Comment: but why...It is just like we declare a variable in the parent class of child class and using  same

Comment: Yes child class can use variable of parent class and this is same happening in this. but for this you need to make connection with interface.

Comment: will you please explain this more. I really want to understand this concept

Comment: Kindly follow this for oulets https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Outlets/Outlets.html

MVC Design Pattern 
https://medium.com/@eliothan/mvc-architecture-for-swift-3-7206b7dc985a